# Round a float to the smallest number keeping a few decimal places

Tags: python, pandas

I need to round a column with floats to 2 decimal places, but without rounding the data to the nearest value

**My data:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [1.233,1.238,5.059,5.068, 8.556]})
df.head()
    numbers
0   1.233
1   1.238
2   5.059
3   5.068
4   8.556
```

**Expected output:**

```
    numbers
0   1.23
1   1.23
2   5.05
3   5.06
4   8.55
```

#### The problem

Everything I've tried rounds the numbers to the nearest number (0-4 is 0 and 5-9 is added 1 to the truncated decimal place)

**Examples of what didn't work**

```
df[['numbers']].round(2)
#or df['numbers'].apply(lambda x: "%.2f" % x)

#output
    numbers
0   1.23
1   1.24
2   5.06
3   5.07
4   8.56
```

Comment: As with the math package in most high-level languages, you're looking for the `floor` function, with its precision argument.

Comment: @Prune I looked at math.floor and np.floor but they round the number to an integer

Comment: Right ... so if your unit is "cents" or "hundredths" ... ?

Comment: @Prune The numbers can have 'n' decimal places, but I need to "floor" them in two

Comment: Right ... so ... never mind, I see that the idea I wanted you to derive, is provided explicitly in an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more like round down

```
df.numbers*100//1/100
Out[186]: 
0    1.23
1    1.23
2    5.05
3    5.06
4    8.55
Name: numbers, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, works well also

```
import pandas as pd
do = lambda x: float(str(x).split('.')[0] +'.' + str(x).split('.')[1][0:2])
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': list(map(do, [1.233,1.238,5.059,5.068, 8.556]))})
print(df.head())
```

output

```
numbers
0     1.23
1     1.23
2     5.05
3     5.06
4     8.55
```

Comment: I don't think converting the float to string is a good idea but thanks for the effort :-)

Comment: by the way, if the float has more than 3 decimal places the code doesn't work =/